# Evitar Traducción de Google

Tags: html, google-chrome

¿Hay alguna manera de evitar que un usuario de la página pueda traducirla  usando las opciones de Chrome?

> [image: Accesando por este icono]

Bloquear esa opción seria lo primordial o evitar que se pueda traducir la página.

Answer (score 18):

Agrega la siguiente etiqueta meta en el header de tu página:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

Esta metaetiqueta indica a Google que no quieres que proporcionemos una traducción de esta página.

---

Documentación de referencia: [Meta etiquetas que Google entiende](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812) <sub>en inglés</sub>

Comment: Eso solo resuelve cuando ingresas no salga el icono pero cuando le das click derecho a la pagina si sale la opcion de traducir

Comment: Sin intención de crear ruido, porqué has rechazado mi edición alanfcm? Podrías haberla rechazado y mejorado, porque como te mencioné en el comentario, la documentación del link no está en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar translate="no", esto sirve no solo para GoogleChrome sino también para los demas navegadores y no te traduce asi le des click derecho y y traducir.

Comment: ¿Dónde agrego eso? ¿Puedes publicar un ejemplo para comprobarlo?

Comment: asi   se usa <body translate="no"><body/>